# Missing objects from project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was doing some work on a application, and went to run the program, and it just opened a basicly blank screen for the program. I then closed out of it and checked the Designer and it seems all my buttons/labels/ect are missing.

The weird part is, they are all still on the dropdown list, but when I select one and try to move it (with arrow keys) I get a message:

> "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I tried to rightclick the background, and click "Send to back", no change. I even tried to remove it, and nothing is behind it... I am at a loss...

He is a picture of what I am talking about if it helps.

[image]

Normally there are labels/buttons all over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Some how in the *.Designer.vb* lines got removed.

Had this in my back up

```
 Me.ButterscotchTheme.Border = True
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.ExpandToggle)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.MinButton2)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.ExitButton2)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.TipBar)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.ButterscotchVerticalTabControl1)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Icon = Nothing
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Name = "ButterscotchTheme"
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(563, 291)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.TabIndex = 22
```

And this in the current

```
 Me.ButterscotchTheme.Border = True
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.MinButton2)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Controls.Add(Me.ExitButton2)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Icon = Nothing
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Name = "ButterscotchTheme"
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(563, 291)
    Me.ButterscotchTheme.TabIndex = 22
```

Not sure how it happened, but its fixed!